# Open opportunity must have an open task

Tags: opportunity

Is it possible to make it mandatory for an open opportunity to have at least one open task?

I was thinking it would be good to create a roll-up summary field to count the number of open tasks - and use that as a validation rule (ie. no. of open tasks must be greater than 0) in order to edit/save an opportunity? But I understand you can't create a roll-up summary for tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it makes sense logically to do so, but it's certainly possible to code this in a trigger. Keep in mind that you do *not* want to do this on insert, because a child record cannot exist before its parent. Here's a trivial example:

```
trigger verifyTaskOpenOpps on Opportunity (before update) {
    Set<Id> hasOpenTasks = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
        [SELECT COUNT(Id) total, WhatId Id
         FROM Task WHERE IsClosed = FALSE AND WhatId IN :Trigger.new
         GROUP BY WhatId]
    ).keySet();
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        if(!(record.IsClosed || hasOpenTasks.contains(record.Id))) {
            record.addError('Please add an open task to this opportunity before updating.');
        }
    }
}
```

Feel free to adjust this code to suit your coding style/methodology.